# Swift is it possible to update UILabel when UIstepper in a custom tableview cell , is increase or decrease

Tags: swift

I am trying to update a UIlabel through refreshLabel() outside of the tableview as the stepper changes value.Have seen multiple examples using eventhandlers but do not know how to use them.(would like the easiest way as im am new to swift.)
CustomCell code

```
    import UIKit

    class cartTVC: UITableViewCell , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
        var collectionCell : cartCVC!

        @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
        @IBOutlet weak var lblPrice: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var lblQuantity: UILabel!
        var img : UIImage?
        var name = ""
        var index : Int?
        var quantity : Int?
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            collectionView.reloadData()
            stepper.wraps = true
            stepper.autorepeat = true
            stepper.maximumValue = 100
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
            layer.borderWidth = 2
            layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                    layer.cornerRadius = 10
            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @IBAction func valueChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
            var cart:[CartItems]
            if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext{
                let data = try? context.fetch(CartItems.fetchRequest())
                cart = data as! [CartItems]
                cart[index!].quantity = Int16(stepper.value)
                cart[index!].totalPrice = cart[index!].price * Int64(cart[index!].quantity)
                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
                lblQuantity.text = String(stepper.value).description
                lblPrice.text = "\(cart[index!].totalPrice) CREDITS"

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it should change label

Comment: Its not the label inside the tableviewcell class . its in the viewcontroller holding the tableview

Comment: write it in cell class